# Creating 'middleman' headset button controller in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

All,

I have searched for an answer to this, but I'm not getting anything exact... It's my first time writing an Android app, so please be gentle :)

I'm pretty bummed about the minimal headset support in Android - unlike e.g. iPhone, it only natively seems to support a single button, so no volume control on headset compatibility. Additionally, if I'm listening to music and a call comes in, the OS pauses the music automatically, but the headset button still functions ONLY as a media button - I can't use it to answer/end the call. If I answer the call via the screen and press the headset button, the music starts again, but the call continues...

I'd like to create a 'middleman' app that can pick up that the headset button has been pressed (via Keyevent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) and can then determine whether to perform the default ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON action (toggle play/pause in my chosen media player) or, if there is an incoming call, pause the music and answer the phone (and then, when pressed again, end the call and restart the media player). Perhaps even check for ACTION_MULTIPLE on the headset button to assign different options (ACTION_MEDIA_NEXT, ACTION_MEDIA_PREVIOUS etc.). Perhaps also be able to determine whether different buttons on the headset have been pressed (if the headset is e.g. a fancy iPhone headset) and 'translate' those button presses into the appropriate ACTION_MEDIA_*). This might not be possible if the OS can't tell the difference between different buttons, obviously.

Obviously such an app would have to receive the intent with a high enough priority that it would be able to abort the broadcast before the current media player gets it.

I've been tinkering with creating assorted BroadcastReceiver classes and intent filters etc., but part of the problem is that the bult-in Android emulator that comes with Eclipse doesn't seem to have the ability to simulate a user plugging in the headset and/or subsequently clicking the headset button. Therefore, every time I get somethign that looks promising, I have to put it onto my actual phone and try it out - time-consuming and a hassle.

3 questions then:

1. Am I missing somethign obvious - is this a real problem and if so, has it already been solved?
2. If it IS a problem, is it possible to write such a middleman app?
3. Are there any other Android emulators that can check for headset-related activities?

Thanks,

Rory

Comment: I don't know anything about headsets in particular, but it should be really straightforwards to deploy onto your phone.  Just plug it in with a USB cable, and when you run the Android app from eclipse it will be deployed on your phone.  No harder than running on the emulator.

Comment: Mayra, you're right that it doesn't seem like it would be too bad, but since I keep the emulator open, copying the app there takes a couple of seconds, whereas copying it to the phone takes significantly longer. Maybe 'cause I only have USB 1.0 (long story!). Plus, I don't like putting apps on my phone unless I know they work great (which my stuff almost certainly won't!).

Comment: Actually, one further question I should have asked: If it is possible to have such an app, will it work on a non-rooted phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i´ve already written exactly this kind of app. Its called like the topic of this thead: Headset Button Controller ;-)

http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.kober.headset/Headset-Button-Controller

Cheers Christoph

Comment: Christoph: Great, so I don't need to write my own Headset Button Controller :) Does this allow incoming call pickup via the headset button too?

Comment: OK, just read where it says that the latest version does indeed have answer/hang up logic implemented. I'll let you know if it works on my Droid X.

Comment: Yup, it works great. @Martin, if you're looking form a nice little app, Christoph's is pretty cool.

Comment: Just for convenience, [market link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headset).

Comment: Just for anyone following up on this, Christoph's app works great, so I shelved writing my own app and just use his.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Hi Christoph,

Your Headset Controller app is doing exceptionally good, I am developing one application which can handle the headset events.

With Your application i am getting Proper headset intents from background and i am able to handle it in my application.

If Headset controller application not installed in Samsung s5 Device, I am not able to get background intents.

please help me on this. Thanks in advance..